# Value error occured when I try to apply argmax to the array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

An error occurred when I applied `np.argmax` function.

> ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence

I have a series `r_1` with all numbers like 0.008540and 0.004844 in a dataframe `full`. The column showed as 0.0 when I use `full.r_1`.

```
0       0.0
1       0.0
2       0.0
...

Name: r_1, Length: 250, dtype: float64
```

For `full.r_1.value_counts()`:

```
0.000000     10
0.008540      1
0.004844      1
...

Name: r_1, Length: 250, dtype: int64
```

After converting it to an array `arr = full.r_1.to_numpy`:

```
array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ..., nan, nan, nan])
```

Then, when I used

```
    i = np.argmax((np.maximum.accumulate(arr))/np.maximum.accumulate(arr))
    j = np.argmax(arr[:i])
```

> `i` is 0 here, so

It returned:

> ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence

Thank you for the comment.

Comment: What is the value of `i`?

Comment: This is not conversion issue. `i` must be `0` here so you are getting empty array which cause the error in `np.argmax`